# Unexpected rendering of nested div tags with same css class in react-admin show view - why and how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-admin

I made a custom `ShowView` in react-admin 3.2.4 view to show a large form for print.
While fine-tuning the css classes I noticed that there are two nested divs rendered with my custom css class `arbeitserlaubnis_frame`. Since the code is like below, I expected only one `div` with that particular class name.

```
 <ShowController {...props}  >
    {controllerProps =>
        <ShowView {...props} {...controllerProps} actions={<PostShowActions />}>
            <SimpleShowLayout >
                <div className="arbeitserlaubnis_frame" id="print_content1">
                [...]
                </div>
            </SimpleShowLayout>
       </ShowView>
   }
  </ShowController>
```

This is the result in the DOM:

[image: DOM Snippet]

**Questions:**

1. Why is it so?
2. How can I fix it that only one div with class `arbeitserlaubnis_frame` is rendered?